# Select rows in SQL partially matching an input input

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to select rows in my table (I'm using Google Sheet for that purpose) which content is included in the string.

For example, rows included in table called `Jobportal`, column `Test`:

```
How to find work
Work permit
Jobs
Temporary jobs
```

I want to select all the rows that contain any word of my input, so if I write *"i'm looking for a job"*, I need to select rows `Jobs` and `Temporary jobs`. If I write "where is my work?", I need to select `How to find work` and `Work permit`.

I've tried this query, but it's returning wrong/unexpected results.

```
 select * from Jobportal where 'im looking for a job' LIKE CONCAT('%',Test,'%');
```

Comment: You might want to use a fulltext index for that. Because otherwise you need to split the search phrase into words and then `OR` search with each word. This solution is not optimal if you take words like "is", "and", "to" into consideration. A search that is performed with the help of a fulltext index might help with that kind of problem. For mysql you might find something here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions.  Assuming that what the user types does not have special characters:

```
where test regexp replace('im looking for a job', ' ', '|')
```

That said, for performance you might want to consider using [full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) capabilities.